# Observe sweetalert2 confirm with javascript in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sweetalert2, shinyjs

I have switched to sweetalert2 since the old version is more limited than the new version which is actively developped.

I am running into a problem however, the code I used to observe confirm or cancel in the old version is not working for me anymore.

In the old version I used to add a function in the '`myjava`' code after

```
closeOnConfirm: true}
```

namely:

```
,
 evalFunction = function(isConfirm){
if (isConfirm === true) {
var val1= 1;
Shiny.onInputChange('option1', [val1, Math.random()]);
}
else  {  
var val2= 2;
Shiny.onInputChange('option2'', [val2, Math.random()]);
}
}
```

but that doesn't work with sweetalert2 it seems.

I tried to try and make the examples on the site work but no luck. https://sweetalert2.github.io/
They use a structure like :

```
.then((result) =>  {
  if (result.value === true) {
  swal('Processing');
    } 
});
```

but it keeps resulting in a 
*Warning: Error in : shinyjs: Error parsing the JavaScript file: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >.*

Here is the app to test it with. You will need to change the directory and download the two files to make `sweetalert2` work 
here: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2

download button is on the right of the title **sweetalert2**
and the 2 files needed are in the **dist** folder named:

**sweetalert2.min.js  &  sweetalert2.min.css**

```
setwd('FOLDER WHERE THE sweetalert2files are ')

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
  var defaultParams = {
    title : null,
    html : null
  };
  params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
  swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, 
    showConfirmButton : true,
    confirmButtonText : 'Left',
    confirmButtonColor: '#00cc00',
    showCancelButton : true,
    cancelButtonText : 'Right',
    cancelButtonColor :  '#339fff',
    closeOnCancel : true,
    allowOutsideClick: true,
    allowEscapeKey: true,
    closeOnConfirm: true});
};"

ui  <- fluidPage(

  actionButton(inputId = 'messagebutton', label = 'click me'),

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = myjava),
  tags$head(includeScript("sweetalert2.min.js"),
            includeCSS("sweetalert2.min.css")
            )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  observeEvent(input$messagebutton, { 
    shinyjs::js$swalFromButton( title = paste('<span style ="color:#339FFF;">An alert with a choice'),
                          html = paste('Pick left or right'))

      })

  observeEvent(input$option1, { print('confirm choosen')})
  observeEvent(input$option2, { print('cancel choosen')})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**
I tried endless variations of this javascript, removing the problematic > symbol as was suggested, but R keeps throwing 'error parsing the javascript code provided.

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
var defaultParams = {
title : null,
html : null
};
params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, 
showConfirmButton : true,
confirmButtonText : 'Left',
confirmButtonColor: '#00cc00',
showCancelButton : true,
cancelButtonText : 'Right',
cancelButtonColor :  '#339fff',
closeOnCancel : true,
allowOutsideClick: true,
allowEscapeKey: true,
closeOnConfirm: true}).then((result){
  if (result.value === true) {
swal('Processing');
} 
});
};"
```

Comment: Instead of writing `.then((result) => ...` can't you write `.then(function(result) ...` ? It looks like shinyjs does not like the `>`.

Comment: Tried, and updated the answer, can't get the correct syntax working Stephane. javascript is still a huge struggle for me compared to R coding

Comment: No. `then(function(result){`, not `then((result){`.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the rest of the code to send variables back to R shiny server working as well now.

Comment: Nice. FYI I already did a Shiny app using sweetalert2 but without using shinyjs. Unfortunately I don't currently have the computer in which it is saved.

Comment: i'd be curious to see it in the future

Comment: Ok, I will try not to forget you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stéphane Laurents comments, this is the solution: 
Including the means to send a variable back to R shiny.

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
var defaultParams = {
title : null,
html : null
};
params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, 
showConfirmButton : true,
confirmButtonText : 'Left',
confirmButtonColor: '#00cc00',
showCancelButton : true,
cancelButtonText : 'Right',
cancelButtonColor :  '#339fff',
closeOnCancel : true,
allowOutsideClick: true,
allowEscapeKey: true,
closeOnConfirm: true})
.then(function(result){
  swal('succes');
  if (result.value === true) {
 var val1= true;
  Shiny.setInputValue('option1', val1, {priority: "event"});}  
else { 
swal('failure');
var val2= true;
          Shiny.setInputValue('option2', val2, {priority: "event"});}  
});
};"
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to include the `Math.random()` if you set the property `priority = "event"`, like this: `Shiny.setInputValue("option1", val1, {priority: "event"});`. The function `Shiny.setInputValue` is the same as `Shiny.onInputChange`, but its name is better. Ref: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

Comment: Good to know, but for the amount of time this code is running I don't think it will have a big impact, but good to know that there is a newer, slightly cleaner way of coding it

Comment: Stephane, I'm now looking at the next hurdle, namely getting text input alerts with validation steps working in the new version. Would you have a chance to help me with those?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean. Which "new version" ?

Comment: I posted a new question