# sweetalert2 text input with validation of the text with javascript in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sweetalert2

I am upgrading from sweetalert to sweetalert2 in R shiny and so far have managed to get the regular response by the R shiny server to ok/cancel buttons in the alert messages working, but now I am stuck with the next type, namely text input messages where I used to perform some validations for:

- empty
- use of special characters 
  before sending the value to R.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450161/observe-sweetalert2-confirm-with-javascript-in-r-shiny/53457439?noredirect=1#comment93787989_53457439) you can find an app in which sweetalert2 is implemented.

in the new problem I'm trying to replace the javascript in that app with a message that holds an input message:

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
      var defaultParams = {
    title: null,
    html : null
    };
    params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
    swal({title : params.title, html : params.html,  
    input: 'text',
    showCancelButton : true,
    showConfirmButton : true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonColor: '#339FFF',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    inputValidator: function(value) {
    if(value === '') { return !value && 'You need to write something!'}
    else {
    var val2= true; 
    Shiny.setInputValue('option2', val2, {priority: 'event'}) };
    }
    });
    };"
```

This works so far, but I have no clue how to add the other check for use of special characters (which are not allowed in file names) 
In my old code I had this line for sweetalert (1) working:

```
 var format = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
 if(format.test(inputValue)){   
 swal.showInputError('Special characters are not allowed');
 return false;
 }
```

But when I build this, it doesn't work in sweetalert2:

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { swalFromButton = function(params) {       var defaultParams = {
    title: null,
    html : null
    };
    params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
    swal({title : params.title, html : params.html,  
    input: 'text',
    showCancelButton : true,
    showConfirmButton : true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonColor: '#339FFF',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
  inputValidator: function(value) {
if(value === '') { return !value && 'You need to write something!'}
else {
          var format = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
                         if(format.test(value)){   
                           return !value && 'Special characters are not allowed'}
                       else {
                         var val2= true; 
Shiny.setInputValue('option2', value, {priority: 'event'})} 
}
}
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As promised in the other post, here is a solution without `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('sweet',
  function(message) {
    swal({
      title : message.title, 
      html : message.html, 
      input : 'text', 
      showConfirmButton : true,
      confirmButtonText : 'Confirm',
      confirmButtonColor: '#00cc00',
      showCancelButton : true,
      cancelButtonText : 'Cancel',
      cancelButtonColor : '#339fff',
      allowOutsideClick: true,
      allowEscapeKey: true,
      inputValidator: function(value) {
        if(value === '') { 
          return 'You need to write something!'
        } else {
          var format = /\\`|\\~|\\!|\\@|\\#|\\$|\\%|\\^|\\&|\\*|\\(|\\)|\\+|\\=|\\[|\\{|\\]|\\}|\\||\\\\|\\'|\\<|\\,|\\.|\\>|\\?|\\/|\"|\\;|\\:/g;
          if(format.test(value)){   
            return 'Special characters are not allowed'
          } 
        }
      }
    })
    .then(function(result){
      if(result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
        swal('failure');
      } else {
      swal('success');
        Shiny.setInputValue('option1', result.value, {priority: 'event'});
      }
    });
  }
);
"
ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.29.2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"),
            tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.29.2/sweetalert2.min.css"),
            tags$script(js)
  ),
  actionButton("messageButton", "Click me")

)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$messageButton, {
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "sweet",
                              message = list(title = paste('<span style ="color:#339FFF;">An alert with an input text'),
                                             html = "Enter text"))
  })

  observe({print(input$option1)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Stéphane, thanks for sharing! I'll try it today. 
Do you happen to know also how to set the horizontal position of the messages? I used to add a tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.sweet-alert {left: 57%;}'))) but I can't figure out what class name to use to target the sweetalert2 messages

Comment: @Mark I don't know but looking [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/src/sweetalert2.scss) one can see that the CSS classes start with `.swal2`, not `.sweet`.

Comment: Stephane, I ran into another strange issues with the messages. Can you have a look if I post a new question or can we communicate directly somehow

Comment: I dont send the success or failure messages but with both my shinyjs approach and your approach, a new sweetalert2 message with just title, html text, and ok/cancel evalualtion is triggered, but for some reason the text in this 2nd message ends up being printed in an error bar

Comment: @Mark Why don't you open a new question? :-)

Comment: I will do, but its going to be after Christmas. Happy holidays stephane