# Sweetalert2 message with dropdown in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, sweetalert2

**How to build an R Shiny version of a `sweetalert2` message with a dropdown menu in it.** 
I've build quite the number and types of sweetalert messages in R Shiny, but this is a new type for me and I'm stuck on the right way to get the choice from a selectinput inside a message out as text rather than a number.

***Got it working to some extend, but output is number of nth element in list rather than the text strings.....***

The original pure javascript example: [example](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types) under *select* (posted at bottom of this message.

After the demo app I made, which spits out numbers instead of text, I tried this: (following the working solution I build in the end based on this other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618418/sweetalert2-text-input-with-validation-of-the-text-with-javascript-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1&lq=1) question on sweetalerts

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
    var defaultParams = {
title : null,
html : null,
inputOptions: null
};
params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, inputOptions : params.inputOptions,
input: 'select',
inputPlaceholder: 'Select a batchname',
showCancelButton: true,
inputValidator: function(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (value === 'Select a batchname') {
      resolve('You need to select a batchname')
    } else {
      resolve()
    }
  })
}
})
.then(function(result){
  if(result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
  } else {
    Shiny.setInputValue('SweetDropChoice', result.value, {priority: 'event'});
  }
});
};"
```

I think my problem is, is that I have no clue how to use the resolve from the example in my own version properly.

Here is the app to test it with. You will need to change the directory and download the two files to make `sweetalert2` work 
here: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/sweetalert2 ,
download button is on the right of the title: **sweetalert2**
and the 2 files needed are in the **dist** folder named:

**sweetalert2.min.js  &  sweetalert2.min.css**

```
setwd(PASTE LOCATION WHERE YOU SAVED THE SWEETALERT SCRIPTS)

    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)

    myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
        var defaultParams = {
    title : null,
    html : null,
    inputOptions: null
    };
    params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
    swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, inputOptions : params.inputOptions,
    input: 'select',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select a batchname',
    showCancelButton: true})
    .then(function(result){
    if (result.value === 'Select a batchname') {
    resolve('You need to select a batchname:)')
    } else {
    var batchname = result.value
    Shiny.setInputValue('SweetDropChoice', batchname, {priority: 'event'});}
    });
    };"



    ui  <- fluidPage(

      actionButton(inputId = 'messagebutton', label = 'click me'),
      verbatimTextOutput('Choice', placeholder = T),
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = myjava),
      tags$head(includeScript("sweetalert2.min.js"),
                includeCSS("sweetalert2.min.css")
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) { 

      values <- reactiveValues(Choice = '?',
                               Choices = rownames(mtcars)[1:6] ## dummy input to use in the sweetalert with dropdown
                               )

      observeEvent(input$messagebutton, { 
        shinyjs::js$swalFromButton( title = paste('<span style ="color:#339FFF;">An alert with a choice'),
                                    html = paste('Pick a name'), 
                                    inputOptions = values$Choices)
      })


      output$Choice <- renderPrint({input$SweetDropChoice})  ## print output of new sweetalert

    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `result.value` is the index of the choice? In this case I would try to replace it with `inputOptions[result.value]`.

Comment: Hey Stéphane, I barely understand what the last part of my two approaches do/do wrong. I just tried var batchname = inputOptions[result.value]; as replacement but that results in no output at all

Comment: Nope, sorry, replace with `params.inputOptions[result.value]`. Also replace `if (result.value === 'Select a batchname')` with `if (result.value === '')`.

Comment: Ok, half way there. I was closer than I thought it seems. params.inputOptions works and now I get the desired text output coming out of it, but the if statement doens't trigger a red warning bar in the sweetalert yet

Comment: Yes, I've just tested that. The error message in Chrome is *"resolve is not defined"*. I will take a look.

Comment: I'm very curious how you test those things by the way. I'm pretty much running blind by running the app and seeing what happens when I click stuff

Comment: For instance, just after `.then(function(result){`, I put `console.log(result);`. And when I run the app, I open the *console* in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i). Then I can see the object `result` in the console when the OK button is pressed. The console also shows the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version. But that's the same as yours, as far as I can see. Except that I have not included the `if(result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel)` (I'm not sure this is correct BTW, there's no `dismiss` field in `result`).

```
myjava <- "
shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
  var defaultParams = {
    title: null,
    html: null,
    inputOptions: null
  };
  params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
  swal({
    title: params.title, 
    html: params.html, 
    inputOptions: params.inputOptions,
    input: 'select',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Select a batchname',
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValidator: function(value) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (value !== '') {
          resolve();
        } else {
          resolve('You need to select a batch :)');
        }
      });
    }
  })
  .then(function(result){
    var batchname = params.inputOptions[result.value];
    Shiny.setInputValue('SweetDropChoice', batchname, {priority: 'event'});
  });
};"
```

Comment: you're right. It doesn't need to be there actually (the dismiss part). The difference between you and me is that I am just copying things and trying when it comes to javascript, and you probably know what you're doing. I have no clue what the return new Promise(function(resolve) { line does exactly and why we need it

Comment: Finally your `result.dismiss` seems correct (there are some examples here https://sweetalert2.github.io/). Honestly I don't really know what I'm doing in Javascript. I'm using some examples and the console to debug. For example I don't fully understand the `Promise`.

Comment: well, we make a great team than despite our lack of knowledge haha. Next challenge, figure out how to put the sweetalert slightly more to the left in my app with css

Comment: Thanks for the input today Stephane. 
and the alignment;   tags$head(tags$style(HTML(' .swal2-modal {left : -440px}'))),
seems to do it

Answer (score 0):

**@Stéphane**   Strangely I got the other version to work now...

```
myjava <- "shinyjs.swalFromButton = function(params) { 
    var defaultParams = {
title : null,
html : null,
inputOptions: null
};
params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);
swal({title : params.title, html : params.html, inputOptions : params.inputOptions,
input: 'select',
inputPlaceholder: 'Select a batchname',
showCancelButton: true,
inputValidator: function(value) {
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
if (value === '') {
resolve('You need to select a batchname')
} else {
resolve()
}
})
}
})
.then(function(result){
if(result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
} else {
var batchname = params.inputOptions[result.value];
Shiny.setInputValue('SweetDropChoice', batchname, {priority: 'event'});
}
});
};"
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer... Yes, I also included this `inputValidator` and this works.

Comment: Go ahead and post it. I'm curious to see the differences and you deserve the reputation points for getting me there